# Detect changes in a form group with multiple instances of a specific value

Tags: angular, formgroups

First off in advance, I apologize if anything I say doesn't make any sense as I am fairly new to programming. Feel free to correct me/ask for clarification on anything that is ambiguous.

I have a code that detects change as so:

```
    this.myForm.get('terminal.**0**.sparePartCost')?.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
        ...some function executes
    })
```

If I am to add another form group instance, I would access this one with a 1 as opposed to a 0:

```
    this.myForm.get('terminal.**1**.sparePartCost')?.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
        ...some function executes
    })
```

I need to be able to do this but for an indefinite number. In other words is there a way I can access this so that it detects which form group I am refering to. Eg:

```
    this.myForm.get('terminal.**X**.sparePartCost')?.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
        ...some function executes based on the value of X
    })
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: try out formArrays. If you initiate your formGroup by using angulars formBuilder injection, you can just simply swap the command to something like: this._formBuilder.array([]). the resulting array can be modified by patching new formControls like this.myForm.push(new FormControl()); (or this.formBuilder.group({}) for nested formgroups. Formarrays can then be iterated over, subscribing to valueChanges inside a for loop. Although I'm almost certain (haven't tested it tho) that a formArrays valueChange triggers on any form array value change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tj, the use of `get('name.'+index+'.property')` is to manage a FormArray. A formArray can be a FormArray of FormControls (not your case) or a FormArray of FormGroup.

To manage a FormArray of FormGroup, we create a function that return the formArray

```
  get terminalFormArray(){
    return this.myForm?this.myForm.get('terminal') as FormArray:null
  }
```

An usually is util make a function that return a FormGroup, I imagine some like

```
getGroup():FormGroup{
  return new FormGroup({
       sparePartCost:new FormControl(),
       otherField:new FormControl()
  })
}
```

To do some like

```
   myForm=new FormGroup({
       terminal:new FormArray(
           this.getGroup(),
           this.getGroup()
       )
   })
```

But if you want to control the changes of an Field in the formArray you can defined the the function createGroup like

```
getGroup(index):FormGroup{

  index=index || (this.terminalFormArray?this.terminalFormArray.length:0)

  constr group=new FormGroup({
       sparePartCost:new FormControl(),
       otherField:new FormControl()
  })
  group.get('sparePartCost').valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
         ..make something with the res and index..
       console.log(res,index)
  })
  return group;
}
```

And you use as

```
   myForm=new FormGroup({
       terminal:new FormArray(
           this.getGroup(0),
           this.getGroup(1)
       )
   })
```

or

```
   this.terminalFromArray.push(this.getGroup())
```

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cxgr6h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)