# Angular Material - mat-autocomplete not populating in ArrayForm

Tags: angular, angular-material

It is a complex form so please bear with me and I will try to answer all your doubts to get it working.
I am trying to implement mat-autocomplete for my form which has formArray and formGroup. I have autocomplete in 2 places outside the formarray and inside the formarray.
For the autocomplete outside the formarray I have successfully implemented the feature but for the autocomplete inside the formarray I have issues.
I get the below error when I reload the page and no data is loaded inside the autocomplete component.  [![error][1]][1]

```
<div formArrayName="rawmaterialwh">
                <div [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let product of products.controls; let i=index">
                   <legend>{{i+1}}</legend>           
                      <div fxLayout="column">
                        <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
                           <div fxFlex.gt-sm="49" fxFlex.gt-xs="49" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="49">
                              <mat-form-field attr.for="{{'rawmaterialid' + i}}"  class="full-wid mrgn-b-lg">
                                 <mat-label>{{'Raw Material'|translate}}</mat-label>
                                 <input type="text" matInput formControlName="rawmaterialid" [matAutocomplete]="rawMaterialAutocomplete" />
                                 <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #rawMaterialAutocomplete="matAutocomplete"
                                    [displayWith]="showRawMaterialName.bind(this)" (selectionChange)="onProductValueChange($event,i)">
                                    <mat-option disabled selected hidden>{{'Raw Material'|translate}}</mat-option>
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let product_mode of filteredRawMaterial  | async" [value]="product_mode.rawmaterialid">{{product_mode.name}}</mat-option>
                                 </mat-autocomplete>
                                 <mat-error *ngIf="products.controls[i].get('rawmaterialid').hasError('required')"> {{'Select Raw Material'|translate}} </mat-error>
                              </mat-form-field>



                              <!-- <mat-form-field  attr.for="{{'rawmaterialid' + i}}"  class="full-wid mrgn-b-lg">
                                 <mat-label>{{'Raw Material'|translate}}</mat-label>
                                  <mat-select formControlName="rawmaterialid" (selectionChange)="onProductValueChange($event,i)">
                                     <mat-option disabled selected hidden>{{'Raw Material'|translate}}</mat-option>
                                     <mat-option *ngFor="let product_mode of productOption"
                                        [value]="product_mode.rawmaterialid">{{product_mode.name}}</mat-option>
                                  </mat-select>
                                  <mat-error *ngIf="products.controls[i].get('rawmaterialid').hasError('required')"> {{'Select Raw Material'|translate}} </mat-error>
                               </mat-form-field> -->
                           </div>
```

Component code

```
 ngOnInit(): void {

this.filteredRawMaterial = this.form.controls.rawmaterialwh.get('rawmaterialid').valueChanges
      .pipe(
        tap(value => console.log('value in tap ', value)),
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filterRawMaterial(value))
      );

}  
[![form][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw3Wf.gif
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhoTN.gif
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using `FormArray`? There's no `formArrayName` in your template and  `formControlName` should be bound to `i`

Comment: weird for some reason the FormArray line was not showing, now it is showing my the code

Comment: Sorry, I cant' get the structure of your form from the template. What's `rawmaterialid`? And why are you looping through `products.controls` if your FormArray is called `rawmaterialwh`? Would you share the code where you're initializing the form?

Comment: That I use to get the formArray for validation error  

`get products(): FormArray {  
    return this.form.get('rawmaterialwh') as FormArray;
  }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503425/angular-9-formarray-search-operation-executing-for-only-first-dynamic-control/61519813#61519813

Comment: @Eliseo  Thanks for your help. Can you tell me how I can get index of the matcomplete

Comment: see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my comment about [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503425/angular-9-formarray-search-operation-executing-for-only-first-dynamic-control/61519813#61519813), if we need know the index, as we create the formGroup and subscribe in a function, we can use the "index". Is like this [another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68704015/detect-changes-in-a-form-group-with-multiple-instances-of-a-specific-value/68704782#68704782).

You can, e.g. pass the "index" to the function "search_Products" or use pipe.tap when add the group

```
addProductGroup(index) {
    ...
    this.productList$[index] = group.get("product_name").valueChanges.pipe(
      tap(_=>this.index=index),  //<--store in a variable "index" the index of
                                 //   the autocomplete we are changed
      debounceTime(300),
                                 //or pass to the function search_Products
      switchMap(value => this.productService.search_Products(value,index))
    );
}
```